# How to add a custom section in umbraco 6.1.x

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I found [few blogs](http://abrissirba.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/custom-section-in-umbraco-back-office/) on adding new Section to umbraco 6.1.x. But nothing seems to work perfectly. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about creating a custom tree to the dashboard. Refer the following links it will help you,

http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/2011/5/creating-a-custom-content-tree-in-umbraco.aspx#.Ug4fJ21yHIX

http://www.theoutfield.net/blog/2012/07

http://www.richardsoeteman.net/PermaLink,guid,f470b6cf-40da-4aa9-a0d9-7b984fe9bf59.aspx